# Failure "INSTALL_FAILED_SHARED_USER_INCOMPATIBLE" without using "sharedUserId"

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I was starting to learn Android Studio and create a project with the empty activity template. While connecting to a real Mobile Phone using USB and press the "run" button, it turned out to show "install failed" with code "INSTALL_FAILED_SHARED_USER_INCOMPATIBLE".

I have looked up for other similar question, which all impiles **android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"** in **AndroidManifest.xml**. However, there is no such settings in the file at all.

I have also tried to add the setting and generate a key file using **keytool-importkeypair** and **platform.pk8, platform.x509.pem**, it still didn't work.

I didn't install the apk before so it has nothing to do with uninstall or rebuild.

Cound anyone give me some suggestions? Thanks for your time.

Comment: You mean the manifest you see in Android Studio has no such entry. But you have to consider that every used library can add entries or modify settings, therefore you have to look at the final Android manifest.xml from the APK. You can use the Analyze APK feature if AS to load the generated APK.

Comment: @Robert Thanks for your advice. I have tried Analyze APK but still found no such setting in Androidmanifest.xml.